# Routing different urls depending on function using Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, axios

I want to route route different urls depending on the login, which is called by axios in this code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./ComponentStyles.css";

class Login extends Component {

    state = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    }

    handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
        
        this.setState({
          [name]:value
        });
    };

    Login = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const User = {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }
  
        axios({
            url:"/api/login",
            method: "POST",
            data: User
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res === true) {
                console.log('Logged in!');
                window.location = '/Menu';
            }
            else {
                window.location = '/';
                console.log('Failure. Could not Login.');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            window.location = '/';
        })
      };

    // more code

}
```

in this, I want to set the `window.location` depending on the result of the function `user_authMySQL`, which is in this other code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// some code

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const User = req.body;  // Object type: User
    var resultTemp = false;

    // This function recieves a username, password, and callback function
    // result in callback function is true if login succeeds, otherwise it's false
    await user_authMySQL(User.username, User.password, function (result) {
        resultTemp = result;
        console.log(resultTemp); // To see what's stored
        if (resultTemp === false ) 
            console.log("Cannot login, data is invalid.");
        else console.log("Loggin in!");
    });  

    console.log(resultTemp + ' = resultTemp'); // This
    res.json();
});
```

When I run it and use invalid login data, this is what the terminal result:

```
[Server] false = resultTemp
[Server] POST /api/login 200 - - 5.987 ms
[Server] false
[Server] false
[Server] Cannot login, data is invalid.
```

And when correct login data is used, this is the result:

```
[Server] false = resultTemp
[Server] POST /api/login 200 - - 1.258 ms
[Server] true
[Server] true
[Server] Loggin in!
```

The problem is, the app always does `window.location = '/'` but doesn't do the `console.log()` for any of the conditions in the

```
        .then((res) => {
            if (res === true) {
                console.log('Logged in!');
                window.location = '/Menu';
            }
            else {
                window.location = '/';
                console.log('Failure. Could not Login.');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            window.location = '/';
        })
```

I don't know how to route the different urls depending on the function, and any help is welcome :)

Comment: Is `res` a plain boolean value or is it a response object that you need to access into? Have you checked the network tab in the dev tools or logged it to see what it actually is? What sort of routing/navigation library is your app using?

Comment: Do you set the response JSON in your server in `router.post` handling?

Comment: @DrewReese ```res``` in the ```.then((res) => { \* code *\}``` part is supposed to be a plain boolean, but the execution never reaches the ```then``` nor the ```catch```, it gets stuck in the ```axios``` function.

Comment: as @DrewReese said. try `res.json(resultTemp )`. also when receive response should you use `res.data===true` or something else? and try to see what you get in Network tab in your browser when send request

Comment: @Jerry I made those 2 changes and it worked! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

well you have several problems with your code and I highly recommend that you reconsider how you do this login otherwise you need to send the "true" value from the server-side so you can test it later on `res.json(true)` in your case
after that you can test it by `res.data === true`